# creating categories and subcategories using the api catalogCategoryRepositoryV1

Tags: magento2, category, api, category-tree, rest-api

I am able to create categories under default category but I am not able to create sub category while creating a new category under default.
The body I am passing is

```
{
  "category": {

    "parent_id": 2,
    "name": "test_category1",
    "is_active": true




  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
I created a category under deafult category using following request
{
 "category": {
 "parent_id": 2,
 "name": "test",
 "is_active": true
 }
}
 To create a sub category for your new category change parent id equivalent to your response

 You can use below request :
 {
 "category": {
 "parent_id": 42,
 "name": "test1",
 "is_active": true
 }
}
```

Comment: how do I do it for a bulk creation?

Comment: when you create category using REST API, magento will return to you the created category id, you can process the response to get the ID then create another request with the created ID